# coordinate of abelian variety and formal group

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Assume Elliptic curves over local field, E/k,
has good ordinary reduction and
$$E:y^2+axy+by=x^3+cx^2+dx+e$$.
In this case,
we know that with the coordinate system $z$ attached to the formal Lie group $\hat{E}$, $x,y$ can be written like,
$$x(z)=z^{-2}+\ldots, y(z)=z^{-3}+\ldots$$.
I wanna extend this to abelian variety.

Here, my conjecture is as follows;
$X/k$ be an good ordinary abelian variety over local field k with mixed characteristics.
(Residue characteristic $p$)
Let $H\subset X$ be an ample divisor of X, and
in this case, $3H$ is vary ample divisor on $X$. (As mentioned in Milne’s Abelian variety)
We take the coordinate of $X$ , $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, by take a basis of
$$(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(3H))-\{0\})/k^\times$$.
I think , by Bertini's theorem, we can assume that $H$ is irreducible closed subscheme of X passing through the origin of X. (We are considering especially the case, $dim X\ge 2$)
There also exists an exact sequence for ordinary abelian variety (proved in Tate's "p-divisible group"),
$$0 \rightarrow X(p)\rightarrow X(k)\rightarrow \tilde{X}(\kappa(k)) \rightarrow 0$$,
$X(p)$ be a formal Lie group attached to the power of $p$ torsion of X, and $\kappa(k)$ be  the residue field of $k$.
In this sense, we can expand the $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ by a coordinate system of $A(p)$, $t_1,\ldots,t_g$ where $g=dim X$.

I feel, the generalization of the Elliptic case happens.
Suppose, $x_1, \ldots, x_s$ be the basis of
$$(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(2H))-\{0\})/k^\times$$
, and assume the origin of $X$ is in some affine neighborhood of codimension $1$ point.
Then,
$$x_i(t_1,\ldots,t_g)=t_1^{a^i_1}\ldots t_g^{a^i_g}+\ldots$$
, $\sum_k a^i_k=-2$ (if $i\leq s)$ and $\sum_k a^i_k=-3$ (if $i >s)$.

Is this true? Or any other generalization exists?